# Mysql insert, if duplicate value on unique key, insert a different value

Tags: php, mysql, insert, unique-key

Is it possible, when inserting a row with unique field, to change the value that goes into unique field into something different in case of duplicate?

Situation: a user is adding a new article, which name cannot be duplicate. For some reason, the user types the name that already exists in the database.

If using "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" - previous record (with the same name as inserted) gets all new data in other fields (update occurs) - not good.

What is required is, on insert, if the field is unique, and there is a match in DB, change the value being inserted into something like "[DUPLICATE] name".

This will reveal the presence of duplicate and the user will just change the name (which, likely, was inserted as duplicate by error).

Comment: Try the insert. If it fails, change the unique value and hit it again.

Comment: Is there a way to include intermediary (select... where name = "article name") into insert statement, so the select would produce either true (i.e. concatenate name with "[duplicate]" string) or false (the name is inserted as is)?

Comment: `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM` is a thing, so maybe?

Comment: INSERT INTO and SELECT is not possible due to mysql restriction (mysql docs: "you cannot insert into a table and select from the same table in a subquery").


Working solution at this moment:
- go over all field names that are unique (known in advance);
- if duplicate present in DB (i.e. count !=zero) - add timestamp to the value to be inserted/updated.


A modified form of timestamp is used instead of a constant value to avoid making another duplicate, which name (i.e. 'name[dub]') is already present in DB from previous add/edit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to do something like (using prepared statements with mysqli)-

```
 SELECT name FROM table WHERE name=?
```

Bind the variable (I am assuming `$articleName`) and store the result, then check if there is a match with `mysqli_num_rows()`.

If there exists one or more rows, rename the article name.

```
 $articleName=$articleName."[DUPLICATE]";
```

Then insert into the db.

Note: There will usually be no same article names, because a sentence can be constructed in a many ways. Consider building a very smart program to detect that or manually check like they do in SO.